как запушить репозиторий, который я клонировал командой git clone --bare, а затем отфильтровал его git-filter-repo?
Мне нужно почистить старую репу от ненужных фалов.
Я клонировал удаленную репу с флагом --bare, чтобы быстро отфильтровать коммиты. Затем я создал новый пустой репозиторий на gitlab и хочу поместить туда отфильтрованный репозиторий. Мне надо как то преобразовывать мой отфильтрованный репо, скачанный с флагом --bare в обычный, перед отправкой?

Просто добавить remote и запушить туда

а не подскажешь, что делать с файлами lfs? не понимаю как это работает. то есть в первом репозитории есть файлы под lfs. что надо сделать чтобы запушить в новую удаленную репу?

Нет не нужно, что значит в обычный? :)
Вариантов много первое, что приходит в голову это:

добавить новый remote и сделать туда push

git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>
git push <remote_name> 


Если связь с репозиторием из которого клонировал не нужна, то можно через set(он просто заменит remote который есть)

git remote set-url <remote_name> <remote_url>

если что, текущие remote можно посмотреть
git remote -v

Не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду про .ifs файлы, если они были в репозитории и вы их не добавили в .gitignore после клонирования они так и останутся, когда вы их запушите.
